# Asynchronous rollback for spring amqp

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to use rollback/commit functionality of spring amqp.
As per documentation, I need to set **channelTransacted** as true both in rabbitTemplate and in the SimpleMessageContainer.

My end goal is to move all the code in xml based and not annotation approach. But for POC purpose, I am working on the spring-rabbit-helloworld sample.

In my consumer if I am throwing exception, it continues retrying and not making any rollback.

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(this.helloWorldQueueName);
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new HelloWorldHandler()));
    container.setChannelTransacted(true);
    //container.setTxSize(1);
    //container.setRecoveryInterval(1000);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    //container.setRecoveryInterval(1000l);
    container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(true);
    return container;
}
```

And

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    template.setRoutingKey(this.helloWorldQueueName);
    template.setChannelTransacted(true);

    return template;
}
```

The reciever :

```
public void onMessage(Message msg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Received: " + msg);
    throw new RuntimeException("error");
}
```

I tried various combinations, but did not worked.

Our design is such that we are attaching MessageListener (javax.jms.MessageListener) to the container.

Do I need to do anything in the producer as well for this other than setting property of rabbitTemplate?

Comment: What do you mean by `it continues retrying and not making any rollback`? If you throw an exception, message will be requeued

Comment: So does this means, the actual message was rollbacked and this was new message which was requeued? If so, how can I verify?

Comment: The actual message you consume was not rollbacked. AMQP does not support transactional get/consume. The exception initiate a reject of the actual message which is requeue on the server queue. You can verify if a message is republished with the `redelivered` header

Comment: As per documentation, http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e1286, it is possible to have transactions. Please correct me if this is pointing to something else.

Comment: Check [the tx semantic](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html). Transaction is only supported for publishing and ack

Comment: What is missing here then? We are looking for acknowledgements as well. For acknowledgements also, it is saying we have to set the acknowledge mode, which is set to AUTO. What I missing?

Comment: I you want the message to be acked, do not throw an exception or throw (but only in case of an error) an `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` exception

Comment: At time of processing, if some exception comes, I want to rollback the transaction. Else I want acknowledgement to be sent and transaction to get committed. I tried ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException, but no change. Again it is adding back to the queue.

Comment: Check what happens when you set a breakpoint in method `SimpleMessageListenerContainer#doReceiveAndExecute`

Comment: There is some confusion here `javax.jms.MessageListener` - you cannot use a JMS listener with Spring AMQP; this is for rabbitmq, not JMS. In any case, turn on DEBUG logging and all will be clear.

Comment: Do I need to set any transactionManager? For jms messageListener, as RabbitMQ takes any Serializable object, serialize it and call any method of any object; and we are upgrading our messaging component which was consuming MessageListener as argument to register to a queue as listener, so we went ahead with same design, just moved from jms implementation to rabbitMQ (spring amqp)

Comment: And do I need to throw org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException ?

Comment: It did not retried for this type of exception though. But does this means it has sent the session.rollback kind of thing?